# Randomize Function in VB6

Tags: random, vb6

I have been trying to generate a Random number between 0-3 Multiple times everytime I run a program.
I'm using the following code as now:

```
Private Sub scatterfun()
Dim cout As Integer, temvar As Integer
While (cout < 500)
    Randomize
    temvar = CInt(Int((3 * Rnd(1)) + 0))
    If temvr = 0 Then
        Statements
    ElseIf temvar = 1 Then
         Statements
    ElseIf temvar = 2 Then
         Statements
    ElseIf temvar = 3 Then
        Statements
    End If
    cout = cout + 1
Wend  End Sub
```

But every time i run it, it shows me the same random number generation pattern.
How to generate a set of different random numbers everytime?

I can't get how to use Randomizer()

Comment: http://www.fortypoundhead.com/showcontent.asp?artid=23621

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly i was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be simplified (and corrected; yours only gives from 0 to 2) to this:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To 500
    Select Case Int(4 * Rnd())
        Case 0
            Debug.Print "0";
        Case 1
            Debug.Print "1";
        Case 2
            Debug.Print "2";
        Case 3
            Debug.Print "3";
    End Select
Next
```

Try it and see.  The `Randomize` statement only sets the seed to the system timer, and `Rnd(1)` is equivalent to `Rnd()`.  Also, [here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242020(v=vs.60).aspx) the doc on the Rnd function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Randomize Timer
```

instead of

```
Randomize
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem. Your code (with `Statements` replaced by a `Debug.Print` and using @BobRodes bug-fix to return values in range 0-3) works as expected in Excel VBA (which is the same core language as VB6) and produces different streams of numbers on different runs. All documentation on `Randomize` that I've unearthed are explicit that when called with no argument it uses the system timer to seed the random number generation.

Nevertheless, your question and the blog post linked to in the comment by @Marc suggests that there is a bug that effects how VB6 handles `Randomize`, probably a bug that effects some but not other versions of Windows (and/or versions of the VB6 compiler if you are using some older version of Visual Studio). Speculating, there maybe the DLL that contains the VB6 runtime looks in the wrong place for the system timer, triggers an error, and then error handling uses 0 for the seed value passed to `Randomize`.

In any event, as @Grcn noted, `Randomize Timer` is a workaround. But -- if you do use that -- be aware that `Timer` seems to have millisecond resolution and that if you use it in a loop the way that you are, there is a chance that `Timer` will sometimes return exactly the same value. In an extreme case, if the body of the loop is the sort of thing that can be executed a million times per second and you are, as in your example, using a loop which runs 500 times, `Timer` might return the same value all 500 times. You would notice that soon enough, but if the time that it takes to execute the loop is just below the 1 millisecond resolution, you would have a greater than expected number of passes through the loop where you have the same "random" value, but in a way which escapes casual notice. For this reason, the call `Randomize Timer` should be moved from inside the loop to just before it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Function PrintRandom (MaxShow as byte)
i=0
    While i<=MaxShow '
      Randomize 'initial random number. if not use ,number will show same value
      form.print Int(Rnd(20)*10) 
      ' Rnd(20) output 0.75 
      ' *10 to get value 7.5 
      ' Int() function to get integer value 7
      i=i+1
    Wend
End Sub 

Private Sub Form_Activate()
    PrintRandom (4) 'will show 4 number in form
End Sub
```